# why getting the error "The selector did not match any elements"?

Tags: angularjs, routes

my index.html body:

```
  <body>
    <my-forget>Loading...</my-forget>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and forget.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import{RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';

@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/app', name:'login-page', component:'LoginComponent'},
  {path:'/*other', name:'other', redirectTo:['login-page']}
])

@Component({
  selector: 'my-forget',
  templateUrl: '../templates/forget.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ForgetComponent {

}
```

Ignore routing parts.
I'm getting the following errors:
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): The selector "my-login" did not match any elements

The selector "my-login" did not match any elements

I don't have my-login in these files and i don't need it!
What is wrong?

Comment: No one can answer this without boot.ts file. What are the components you are loading in boot.ts holds the key. I am guessing you might be calling 'LoginComponent' which has 'my-login' selector.